# Can anyone identify this blue partial vehicle build?

Tags: set-identification, vehicle

[image]

[image]

I know this is a long shot, but does anyone recognise this set? The pieces in the photos are all common so not much help;

Black plates
2 x 6 (2 of),
2 x 4
2 x 8.
1 X 1 round (2 of).

Blue plates
1 X 2 (2 off),
2 X 4
2 X 2
1 X 4 (2 off)

And a steering wheel and seat.

I believe the set is after the year 2000 but can't be certain.
All guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a glance it doesn't look like a set as much as something someone might have randomly put together. The two blue 1x2 tiles at the front seem odd, as do the double-stacked black round tiles.

Of all the pieces used it seems the rarest would be the blue steering wheel or the [blue seat](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4079&name=Minifig,%20Utensil%20Seat%202%20x%202&category=%5BMinifig,%20Utensil%5D#T=C). It turns out the blue seat piece is used in 'only' [67 different sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4079&in=S).

From that list of sets, only one set seems to resemble this configuration, the [**1572 Super Tow Truck**](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/1572/Super_Tow_Truck) from the Town theme, released in 1986. Step 3 of the instructions (as shown below) seems to be quite a close match.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I guess I was a little bit off with my date!