# Does anyone know or can identify these pieces? Lots of long tan, and blue, and white

Tags: set-identification

[image: long tan, and blue, and white]

I bought this from an auction the box that came with it was from LEGO city but judging from the colors it seems like its the wrong box. Can anyone identify?

Comment: Related: *[Problems with set identification questions](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/)*. E.g., *"Usually I will re-word the title to be more descriptive"*

Comment: The canonical is *[How can I identify Lego sets from a box of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/)*.

Answer (score 25):

The color scheme immediately reminded me of [London Tower Bridge (10214)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10214-1). Since this isn't a sealed set, it is not possible to tell if this belongs to one or several sets. However, the combination of some objects like the assembly in Yellow and Pearl Gold as well as Technic pulley wheels in Tan, the 2x10 brick in Blue and, as I mentioned, the overall color scheme all leads to this set.

[image]

Comment: From the photo OP posted, I thought the tan wheels (semi-hidden behind gray wheels) might be semi-unique. Turns out this is one of the few sets they are found in: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4185&colorID=2&in=A

Comment: In fact, their combined use with the gray wheels is more obvious now that I've looked through other pictures: https://www.bricklink.com/TL/2611.jpg?1

Comment: If this is correct, what a great find at the auction OP!