# There is no bag number for this bag - all yellows and oranges and variants

Tags: set-identification

This bag has yellow and orange parts and the lego tool.
[image: yellows and oranges and variants]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify Lego sets from a box of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-of-parts)

Comment: The lack of a bag number hints strongly at it being a **creativity-type** set instead of a **build-this-and-primarily-this** set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only green parts and there is no bag number for this bag](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/only-green-parts-and-there-is-no-bag-number-for-this-bag)

Comment: This is your 8th or 9th bag question in short succession. And 5 of them only belonged to 2 sets. Just a tip: If you have 1 bag identified check first if any other un-identified bags that you have could belong to the same set. That saves you and us the trouble of another question.

Answer (score 1):

It's also [31105](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=11005-1) based on the green bag you also posted in another question, but also because only that set has all of Yellow Brick 2 x 8, Yellow Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud, and some color of Brick 1 x 1 x 3.

[image: 31105]