# Only green parts and there is no bag number for this bag

Tags: set-identification

Three different colors of green in this[image] bag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify Lego sets from a box of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-of-parts)

Answer (score 3):

[11005-1 Creative Fun](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=11005-1) based on Lime Slope, Inverted 45 2 x 2 with Flat Bottom Pin, Green Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole, Lime Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Bottom Stud Holder

[image: 11005]