# Help identifying bricks set - Tan brown black bricks, gold cones

Tags: set-identification

I have bag of Lego but can’t identify what they are. Package number 7 with 728R0 on the bag. Tan brown black bricks some gold cones and single red piece

Comment: The bag numbering is not specific to any one set, so that will not help, alas. What does the single red piece **look** like? Even better, a photo (or three) will probably let us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify Lego sets from a box of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-of-parts)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the extremely scarce information provided (take photographs when asking for set identifications, **please**!), I've scoured sets containing [1x1 cone in pearl gold](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4589b&colorID=115&in=A):

- With more than one pearl gold cone
- Big enough to have at least seven bags
- With a predominance of tan/brown/black

Of those, the only possible match I could find is [7327-1 Scorpion Pyramid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7327-1). According to the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/7327), bag 7 builds the tip of the pyramid, an obelisk, and some decorations...

[image: Model after bag 6]
[image: Model after bag 7]

... with three pearl gold cones, quite a lot of tan and dark tan (easily mistaken with "brown") and some black, but also some blue parts (that OP doesn't mention), and not one but two red snakes.

I've looked at the instruction booklets of other sets, and bag 7 doesn't match my criteria.

Again, this is based on very limited information, and good photographs of the bag (or the parts themselves) are the reliable way of identifying sets.