# Bag 2, 2011 135149 - 2 minifig heads, lime, brown, greys

Tags: set-identification

Bag 2 has 2 minifigure heads, one black male and one tan female. Gray male hair and black male hair.

[image: Bag 2, 2011 135149 - 2 minifig heads, lime, brown, greys]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify Lego sets from a box of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-of-parts)

Answer (score 5):

[70912-1](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70912-1) Arkham Asylum

I based it on Lime Tile 1 x 6, Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle on Side - Closed Ends, Tan Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom (Boat Stud).

[image: 70912]

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Note also the minifig heads visible are [Barbara Gordon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh337) and [Aaron Cash](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh339)

Comment: I ignored the minifig heads; there are so many subtle variations I find it's not worth identifying based on that.