# How do I identify a new sealed bag of Lego

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

I've bought the Lego set [11019 Fun Functions](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11019-1) for my daughter. Bag number 5 isn’t in it just a blank bag plus the pieces don’t match up with the helicopter instructions number 5 is supposed to make. They don’t match anything else you can make from the box so how can I find out what you are supposed to make from it. I scanned the QR code and it’s number 6172062 on it.

Comment: We really do need a good picture (or three) of the contents of the bag. The QR code on the bag is about the plastic bag itself, used in many different sets, so that won't help identify the pieces inside at all.  But if a bag (#5) is missing, then perhaps the bag you've identified is just an extra bag of fun bits to facilitate free play building, If so, enjoy the extra pieces, but also contact Lego support to let them know your set was incomplete, so they can make it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify LEGO sets from a box or bag of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-or-bag-of-parts)

Comment: In your photograph I can see a lot of the pieces from set 11019 - but what's this "bag number 5" you speak about? Can you please post a photo showing *only* that bag?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I thought bag #5 was missing

Comment: If you suspect you're missing a whole bag, then you should get in touch with customer support. Also: every set has a parts inventory (printer either on the box, or in the instruction booklet). Check if the inventory matches your available bricks.

Comment: Did you find out what it's for? We've got it too but our bag had no number on it at all. We've got all the bags for the ones included in the instructions and then this one. Wondering if it's just a bag of extra bits to make other stuff

Answer (score 1):

I got in touch with Lego and they confirmed the extra bag is just extra bricks to build with.