# Can anyone help me identify what set this pack is from please? white pieces with a distinctive minifig

Tags: set-identification

[image: white Lego pieces with a distinctive minifig]

Hi, I am struggling to identify what set this pack is from. It came randomly with a box of various toys, so nothing for reference!

Comment: Could you add a picture that shows which elements are inside the bag?

Comment: Please note any codes you find on a bag like this are irrelevant in identifying LEGO sets.

Comment: That explains why I can't find anything having searched for these codes! I'll add some more pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify LEGO sets from a box or bag of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-or-bag-of-parts)

Answer (score 5):

[70595](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70595-1) Ultra Stealth Raider is the only set on BrickLink with

- [973pb2520c01](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb2520c01&in=M) Torso Ninjago Tunic with Light Gray Trim and Belt, 3 Dark Gray Ties with Gold Buttons, Dragon Symbol on Back Pattern / White Arms / Sand Green Hands
- [970c00pb0589](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00pb0589) Hips and Legs with Silver Sash and Knee Straps Pattern

(Note: the torso and the legs are from two different figures.)

[image: Ultra Stealth Raider]

[image: Torso Ninjago Tunic with Light Gray Trim and Belt, 3 Dark Gray Ties with Gold Buttons, Dragon Symbol on Back Pattern / White Arms / Sand Green Hands]
[image: Hips and Legs with Silver Sash and Knee Straps Pattern]