# What Harry Potter set is this assembly from?

Tags: set-identification, model-identification

I have been gifted a lot of 10+ years old LEGO. I don't have any instructions books. Any idea what sets could this be so I could try to find them online please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like two [Slope 2x2 45° in sand green](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3039#C=48) and a [Light Brick 2x3x 1 1/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54930c02).

The only set containing both those parts is [4738-1 Hagrid's Hut (3rd edition)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4738-1).

(Now that you know the set number, you can search for instructions in [Lego's customer support webpages](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions))

Comment: Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: @Natalia You're welcome! Since you're new here, I'll remind you that it's good etiquette to "accept" the answer. See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: Thank you again @IvanSanchez, really appreciate it. Have 
I accepted the answer correctly? This forum is amazing. I have so many lego and keep checking for answers here, what element is what numer and what sets etc. And will have more questions, so happy I have registered here.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! You're welcome to come back, but if you got a big unsorted pile you might wanna read https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/ for tips on doing the set identification by yourself.