# I have this bag of mostly reds with light grays

Tags: set-identification

I have this bag of mostly reds with light grays.
Some blues, yellows, and orange.
What set would these legos belong to?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A [search for sets containing 2 4x10 dark red plates and a 2x2 round brick with grille profile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=92947&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=11&itemNo2=3030&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=59&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=&in=S) returns just one hit: [set 21154](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21154-1).

See also [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/18087/13403)