# What lego set has bag 435R6, 525R6, 625R6

Tags: star-wars

I was given a box of legos and some in bags. My daughter wants to build the set but not sure what these are. It looks like they were started and never finished. I know where to get the instructions.

I have multiple bags of 435R6, 525R6 and 625R6. They all appear to be star war sets of 2015.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi jgemoll, and welcome to Bricks SE! The codes on the bags are merely used in the factory, and don't help to identify the sets you have. Your best chance would be to add a photo of the bags and of the partially completed model

Comment: You can also check out the answer to [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags) to try your luck at finding it yourself

Comment: Hi jgemoll and welcome to Bricks.SE! As the other comments, I'd recommend checking out the linked guide and see if you can use that to identify the set yourself. If you have any problems using that, feel free to edit this question with the steps you took and the problems you encountered and we'll gladly help. Meanwhile I'd recommend taking a look at the [tour] and [help] sections to learn how this site operates and how you can get the most out of it. Have fun!