# Trying to find the name of a LEGO set from a sealed bag

Tags: set-identification

I have got a couple of bags which I think are for the same set.

[image]

Comment: Hi Terry and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please note that we already have guides on how to identify sets, like for example here: [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags). After trying the steps described there, edit your question with the details of what you have done and where you got stuck and we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is from [The Skeleton Dungeon (21189)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21189-1) set.

[image]

Identified by [unique combination](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=24866&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=4&itemNo2=22888&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=85&itemNo3=3003&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=14&in=S) of:

- Orange [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (5 Petals)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24866)
- Dark Bluish Gray [Plate, Round Half 4 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22888)
- Trans-Dark Blue [Brick 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3003)