# What is this extra bag from 11019 set for?

Tags: lego-group

This came in the classic 11019 Lego set. No additional instructions. I looked on Lego website and nothing showed up. There was an online locomotive to make? Looks like there’s sets of wheels and gears. Any help is appreciated! The bag that came has the number 135149 copyrighted in 2017

[image]

Comment: i found 2 of them: https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6394760.pdf and https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6394891.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Comment: Nope. I have instructions, but it came with this spare unlabeled bag with lots of extra pieces

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the question? You've already determined that this is from set 11019, and according to the part list of that set, it matches up. Classic sets like this one don't really have instructions because you're meant to make stuff up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As you've mentioned in your question, the bag is from set 11019.

It seems that the confusion arises from the fact that most Lego sets do not have so many "spare" parts as is the case here.

However, with the Lego Classic line you will often find that there are more parts in the set than building instructions. If you look at the box you can note that it says "Ideas included". I've found that when that text is there, the instructions have several smaller individual builds for most of the pieces, but there is an "extra" bag or two with additional pieces which fits the theme - in this case exemplified by the gears.

Answer (score 2):

This set doesn't have an intention to use all the bricks to build a defined set of models. As seen from description below (emphasis is mine) included instructions is a way for young builders to learn using LEGO bricks in new way and more of an inspiration for own builds. Extra bag is just a bag of more bricks to play with.

[Description](https://brickset.com/sets/11019-1/Bricks-and-Functions) for Bricks and Functions (11019) set:

LEGO® Classic creations with fun functions
The LEGO® Classic Bricks and Functions (11019) building set comes with a colorful selection of LEGO pieces and **instructions to make 7 fun buildable toys** with gear-driven functions. Kids get to construct models with moving parts, from a pirouetting ballerina to a helicopter with spinning rotors, **before diving into the bags of extra bricks to build their very own LEGO creations**.

Perfect for children aged 5 and up
Kids will love building and playing with these functional models. And because each one comes with a step-by-step, pictorial building guide, even first-time builders can experience the pride and joy of constructing their own LEGO toys.

Kids develop key life skills
LEGO Classic playsets inspire children to get creative with exciting themes and building ideas that stimulate open-ended play. Learning has never been so much fun!

Create LEGO® models with different functions – The LEGO Classic Bricks and Functions (11019) playset comes with colorful LEGO pieces and **7 mini builds** with gear-driven functions **to kick-start the fun**

- What’s in the box? – All kids need to build a pirouetting ballerina, a push-along helicopter with spinning rotors, an apple with a pop-up worm and more, plus lots of LEGO® bricks for creative building
- Open-ended creativity – Kids get to **build and play with the 7 included model *ideas***, then innovate and discover as they find imaginative ways **to create their very own LEGO® toys**
- A gift for any occasion – The LEGO® Classic Bricks and Functions (11019) toy playset is a gift for any occasion. Suitable for kids aged 5 and up
  Includes 500 LEGO® pieces – Kids can **build whatever they imagine** with this original LEGO playset and can combine it with other LEGO sets for even more creativity
- More sets to collect and combine – Kids can combine this playset with others from the LEGO® Classic range
- Step-by-step, pictorial building guides – **Every model comes with easy-to-follow building instructions, so even first-time builders can experience the fun of constructing their own LEGO® toys**
- Playful learning – Kids develop important creative skills as they build and play
- High-quality creative building toys – All LEGO® Classic components meet strict industry standards to ensure they’re consistent and compatible
- Safety first – All LEGO® building toys are thoroughly tested to ensure every playset meets strict safety standards

Answer (score 0):

Is it [this set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/bricks-and-functions-11019)? The parts appear to match and it has the same set number.
If so, there should be an instructions booklet in the box (not the bag itself) and possibly a QR code somewhere. Otherwise, you can look at the pictures of completed models (7 in all) that appear on the website. If you've already made them, it could just be spare parts! Legos are for creating your own thing. You can experiment with the parts and make your own contraptions :)