# Identify this set: loose bag with rounded gears

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Got this at a Staples/LEGO event and does not have any instructions. When I scanned the QR code it says 6172061 but nothing found on the LEGO website. Anyone knows what this set might be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this extra bag from 11019 set for?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-this-extra-bag-from-11019-set-for)

Answer (score 3):

This bag contains bricks from [Bricks and Functions (11019)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/11019-1/bricks-and-functions/?inventory=1#parts) set. You are not supposed to build particular model(s) with elements included within this set. You can find some inspiration [instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/11019).

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if the bag are extra pieces? Not sure if they are meant for open-play or if there are instructions available? Didn’t seem like so on the Lego site.

Answer (score 0):

The same bag has been asked about earlier:
https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/18162/20578

You can find more details about the intention of it in the answer.