# Help identifying set just with a bag of common bricks

Tags: set-identification

I have a picture of this bag with LEGO bricks in it. Any idea what set this is?

[image: Bag photo]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify LEGO sets from a box or bag of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-or-bag-of-parts)

Comment: Or this? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Comment: ❤️trying to solve this for my patient. Definitely not a Lego aficionado

Comment: Do you have a larger picture? There seems to be a lot of common parts, so it isn't easy to identify anything reasonable at this scale.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the 6 x 12 tan plate and some of the other more basic elements, this appears to be a bag from [Bricks and Houses (11008)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/11008-1/bricks-and-houses/):

[image: Box photo]

If this is the only bag you have, it isn't a complete set and you likely can't build any of the models from the instructions. This set is an assortment of basic elements, so you could still get some good free building value out of the parts you have.