# 2 bags of LEGO bricks without box

Tags: set-identification

Don't know what box these came from and there's no instructions.

[image: boxless bags]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Answer (score 3):

Base on all 6 I identified myself:

1. 1x2 SNOT brick with stud on one side (11211) in Yellow.
2. some 4x4 plates? (3031) in Green
3. 2 2x4 bricks (3001) in Blue.
4. 1x2 Technic (3700) in LBG.
5. 3x3 plate (11212) in Tan.
6. Slope 33 3x2 (3298) in Reddish brown.

If you identified all 6 on Bl results:

This refers to [Set 11018: Creative Ocean Fun](https://brickset.com/sets/11018-1/Creative-Ocean-Fun)
[image]