# Bags in color sets with no instructions

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone identify what Lego set these bags are from?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attached picture seems to be too small to identify any pieces reasonably. Could you post another, higher resolution picture please?

Comment: Hopefully these pictures are better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the yellow 1x4 technic brick and the 4x6 light bley plate, plus the fact that bags containing similar colours are very common in "classic" sets, this can be identified as part of [11021-1 "90 years of play"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11021-1).

[image: set 11021]

Comment: If you look closely at the yellow bag there are black rubber wheels and there are no items with wheels in that set; plus that set has numbered bags. These bags do not have any numbers. 
That set of cassis Lego bags did get thrown into a bin with these bags though

Comment: @AaronJ This is a unique set, in that a portion of the parts are used to create the models on the box, and the rest are miscellaneous parts for your imagination. If you check the inventory of this set you'll see that it does indeed contain the aforementioned tyres.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate it!