# What set do these four bags belong to?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Found these four sealed bags. Any idea what set they go to?

Comment: I've got a few parts leading to [this query](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=15303&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=17&itemNo2=92099&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=85&itemNo3=47398&itemSeq3=2&colorID3=86&in=S) leading to 4 sets. I'm thinking this is a millenium falcon but cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Comment: @LKBricks you can clearly see an experienced member of this community is struggling to identify the set. What kind of outcome do you expect OP (a new (!) contributor) would be able to get out of the linked article?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with [IvanSanchez's search](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=15303&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=17&itemNo2=92099&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=85&itemNo3=47398&itemSeq3=2&colorID3=86&in=S) (sets with at least two of trans-red projectile 8L, two of dark bley 4x6 plate w/ door hinge, two of light bley 3x12 wing/wedge), this is probably the 2019 millenium falcon [75257](https://brickset.com/sets/75257-1/Millennium-Falcon)

If you look correctly bag 7 contains C3PO and in bag 8 is a R2D2 body.
When going through the [instruction](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6320661.pdf) of this set you see C3PO is in bag 7 and R2D2 is in bag 8

[image]
[image]

Comment: So *that's* what the golden bits in bag 7 were. Good eye!

Comment: I only recognized it when going through the instructions. Was more focused on finding the red part in bag 8 in the instructions