# Need help identifying two unopened bags of Lego

Tags: set-identification, bag-build

We were cleaning out a drawer in my son’s room, and we found two unopened bags of Lego. We don’t know what sets they are from. Bag 2 has a brown oar and a black bat (like the animal)in it. Can anyone help us figure it out? Thank you so much! [image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the parts

[Black Bar 1.2L with Top Stud and 4 Bar Arms Up (Palm Tree Top)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566)

and

[Light Bluish Gray Wedge 4 x 4 (Slope 18 Corner)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43708)

these bags [can only come](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=2566&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=11&itemNo2=43708&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=86&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=0&in=S) from

[40597 Scary Pirate Island](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40597-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]