# Help me identify set so we can get instructions

Tags: set-identification

[image]

We found this LEGO set, but we don’t have instructions or set number.
Is there any way to identify what is the set?

Comment: It might be that these bags are from different sets. Could you take pictures of each bag individually and edit your answer to include them please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags)

Answer (score 4):

The numbered bags I immediately recognise as part of the [BOOST Creative ToolBox](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=17101) The unnumbered bag also seems to contain parts of the Boost set in addition to a couple of elements that got mixed in between I think.

I think the Boost set was a very interesting robotics set that unfortunately was underappreciated and hence phased out way too soon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is [17101 "BOOST creative toolbox"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=17101-1).

[image: set picture]

This is based on some parts in bag 8:

- [5x1 rounded technic plate with axle hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32124), in white, at least three occurrences
- [Bracket 1x2 to 1x2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99781), in orange, at least six occurrences
- [2x1x2/3 curved slope](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11477), in dark azure, at least six occurrences

Bag 7 has to be the tank treads, bag 9 contains the plate for the basketball hoop, bag 10 contains the trans-orange half-sphere.

The set also has two [big solid 54mm x 30mm wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2515), which are visible in the unmarked, closed-with-a-pink-hair-tie bag at the top.This leads me to think that the entire set has been repackaged (which befuddles me, since the original bags are flimsy as heck once torn open)