Identify this set: 12 bags with light tan, sand green and trans green
No instructions, only unopened parts packages found at thrift store. 1-6 and 8-13.  Missing bag 7 and probably some after 13, as there are no minifigs or accessory pcs. Can anyone identify this set?


I think I see a QR code on one of the bags, can you try scanning that?

As usual for this kind of question, please read https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags

The sheer amount of 2x2 round bricks in trans-bright green tells us this is set 75255-1 Yoda sculpture.
Note how the rest of the bags contain parts in sand green and light tan, matching the parts visible in the set.

