Identifying random Lego bag
I have a random Lego bag. It has the numbers 127S5 and 1.

As usual with this kind of question: The numbers on the bag doesn't say anything about the set. I even suspect that the "1" just means it bag number 1, so we can conclude that it's a set with a minimum of 1 bag.  If you upload a picture of the bag, we have a chance, but you can also just read one of the many questions here about identifying sets, e.g. https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-can-i-identify-a-set-based-on-one-or-more-original-sealed-bags

Hi Sarah and welcome to Bricks.SE! As other commenters have already noted, the information you have provided is not enough to identify the set it came from. Please edit your post with at least a photo - but more details would also be useful. Play well!
