# Set identification: Ninjago style dragon

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

Can someone identify the set containing this (part of probably) creature?

Found it in a box at a thrift sale, along with 2 ninjago motos and snake-headed minifigs, all of this may or may not be in the same set.

[image: part of dragon with plastic wings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify LEGO sets from a box or bag of parts?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-can-i-identify-lego-sets-from-a-box-or-bag-of-parts)

Comment: I'm not fluent enough in english, so I know neither english part names nor english color names making those tools extremely difficult / impossible to use for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like (part of) [70674-1 Fire Fang](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70674-1) which is indeed a Ninjago set.

[image: fire fang ninjago lego set]

I identified this the hard way, using [Dark Tan Barb/Claw/Horn/Tooth Small](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=53451&colorID=69&in=A) which looked fairly unique but is actually in many sets.